# Type to second level slice of struct

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct like this

```
type Item struct { 
    Data []struct {
        meta struct {
            ID int
        }
    }
}

func main () {
    _, value := range Item.Data {
        getId(value)
    }
}

func getId(v Item.Data) {
    return v.ID
}
```

In `getId()` function, how can I type hint to a value of `Item.Data` struct? Or pass the piece of `Item.Data` to `getId` correctly?

I have created a modified simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of quick notes :

- that isn't valid Go
- be careful with public vs private (first letter upper or lower case)
- go isn't object oriented
- loops start with `for`
- `_, value := range Item.Data` iterates over a type, not an instance, which doesn't work.
- you might be tempted to save lines of code, don't do that in Go.

Nested struct definitions are IMHO only useful for one off types. For example if you are serialising data from JSON to Go you might need some temporary structures while converting.

If however you are defining types to be used through out your program you should define each separately. This makes it much easier to extend and use these types.

If each type is defined on its own it is easy to add a method on your `data` type that returns the `id` of the `meta` field.

To make everything obvious I named things `...Type` and `...Field`, you don't need to do that, and it isn't a good practice ;)

```
func (d dataType) getId() int {
    return d.metaField.idField
}
```

Full example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type dataType struct {
    metaField metaType
}

type metaType struct {
    idField int
}

type itemType struct {
    dataField []dataType
}

func (d dataType) getId() int {
    return d.metaField.idField
}

func main() {
    item := itemType{
        dataField: []dataType{
            dataType{
                metaField: metaType{
                    idField: 1,
                },
            },
        },
    }

    for _, value := range item.dataField {
        fmt.Println(value.getId())
    }
}
```